# Reconnect event: too many minutes, sometimes hours

Tags: asp.net, signalr, owin, azure-application-insights

We just added our application to Microsoft Insights to analyze some performance issues.
The thing that called our attention, was /signalr/signalr/reconnect request.
Bellow, you can see that avg of this event is about 22.51 minutes:

[image]

When click on the reconnect event, the thing get worse, the second event took more than a hour to release:

[image]

The question is: Is that normal? Could it be any relationship with high CPU usage?

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal for signalr connections. Singalr opens what is called a "hanging" connection that allows two-way communication between client server and doesn't end request for a long period of time. Introduction to signalr: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr. If you would like to exclude signalr requests from monitoring, please use [telemetry processor](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/request-filtering-in-application-insights-with-telemetry-processor/) to filter them out.